# Does in streams collect/map call all methods exactly once?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of Objects and want to retrieve the minimum and maximum of a certain value of all of them and reset this value. My solution to this is to have a method in the Object class, which returns the value and resets it and a Min-Max collector . Hence my question: Does `collect`/`map` call every method (in this case the `getAndResetValue()` method) exactly once per instance or could the following get broken?

```
MinMax minMax = objects.stream()
                   .mapToInt(e -> e.getAndResetValue())
                   .collect(() -> new minMax(startValues), MinMax::addValue, MinMax::compareMinMax);
```

My educated guess would be, this is true, since there is no need to call the methods several times and every Object must be mapped. But since I found no confirmation on this matter (not even in the docs), this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "call every method exactly once"? Which method? What does "called once" mean for you?

Comment: The `getAndResetValue()` method. Calling once means for every instance this stream should call this method exactly once, since more often would get wrong results.

Comment: The method `getAndResetValue` will be called as many times as there are elements in the Stream.

Comment: So _exactly_ once per instance?

Comment: Which instance? If you have 4 different elements, the method `getAndResetValue` will be called once on those 4 different elements. But you should have stateless mapper which is not the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While current Stream API implementation calls the function supplied to `mapToInt` only once per input element, it's not specified and it's required by the specification that the supplied function is stateless which is wrong in your case. So I would not recommend writing code like this. Also note that the input collection might contain the same object twice (e.g. `objects = Arrays.asList(obj, obj)`), in this case it will be called twice even with current implementation.

Comment: The second case is prohibited by my code before, but it is good you mentioned it. But the first thing you mentioned convinced me to follow your advice and make two streams. One to collect and one to reset. The performance reduction should be acceptable. Thanks. EDIT: Well then in this case seems a good old for-loop better.

Comment: NB, it also specifies [non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), which is modifying the collection while the pipeline is being executed.

Comment: @ctst, note that you don't need to use Stream API for the second problem. Just use `objects.forEach(e -> e.reset())` (assuming that `objects` is a collection).

Comment: @weston, OP does not modify the source, it modifies the elements in the source. It's the different thing. Modifying source is, for example, calling `objects.add` inside the `mapToInt`.

Comment: Correct, I didn't mean to imply that they were. Just a side note for OP's benefit. It also includes details on what it means to be stateful.

Comment: @TagirValeev: That's exactly what I now implemented. There is a slight performance drawback, since now I don't use the merge of MinMax, but this is acceptable.